# web scraping using selenium in c# - getting javascript variable

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get a javascript variable using selenium. Here is the page source link:

view-source:https://school2school.net/stations/?siteCode=TA00279&variableCode=temperature

In the javascript portion, there is an array of the value name series. How do I scrape that data using C#?

Comment: Please show where is the javascript portion you mean, there are many ones. At least you can give the variable name or a code line in the javascript portion, so that we can search.

Comment: variable name is "series". It's an array I already told in question

Comment: You need to add the relevant code from the page into your question because the site may change at some point and it's not clear here what you are referring to. You also need to add your code attempts with some more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do. An example would probably help also.

Comment: Thanks to whom for downvoting :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

string script = "return JSON.stringify($('#tempcontainer_local').highcharts().options.series)"
string data = (string)js.ExecuteScript(script);

// convert JSON string to JSON object in c#
...
```

Comment: I got it working with another solution. Thank you anyway

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi, why not publishing your solution here?

Comment: Hi, @yong. This is a great solution and worked perfectly!